# Implement spelling corrector into my android dictionary app

Tags: android

I'm developing a dictionary app and I would like to implement spelling corrector (like google search engine: "Did you mean ....") into my android dictionary app. Can I do so? How to code it? Anyone can help out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an algorithm such as Levenshtein distance to calculate how off a word is to other words in a pre-defined wordlist, if there is no exact match in the word list, you can propose the one that is closest (and add a word to it if the user still selects his/hers version/spelling).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance